# Using Input Radio in Visualforce page with Apex Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectradio

I am having trouble using apex:selectradio because of 508 compliance issues. The selectradio is creating html table tags with role="presentation" and the tool my client is using treats it as a layout table and not data table and fails to read the labels for the radio button.

The solution I have come up with is to use input type radio and pass the values to to controller, but I cannot fire submitSatisfactionComment method.  Here is my code.

VisualForce Page:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="satisfactionComment"  name="satisfaction" value="1"> {!$Label.One}
        <apex:actionFunction name="satisfactionComment" action="{!ctrl.submitSatisfactionComment}" rerender="myPanel"/>
    </input>
<input type="radio" onclick="satisfactionComment"  name="satisfaction" value="2"> {!$Label.Two} 
       <apex:actionFunction name="satisfactionComment" action="{!ctrl.submitSatisfactionComment}" rerender="myPanel"/>
    </input>
```

Apex Code:

```
public PageReference submitSatisfactionComment()
{
    //do something here with the selected value of the radio button
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem, exactly?

Comment: The method is not firing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never used action function before as a child of the inputs, usually just use action support

```
<input type="radio" name="satisfaction" value="1"> {!$Label.One}
        <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!ctrl.submitSatisfactionComment}" rerender="myPanel"/>
    </input>
<input type="radio" name="satisfaction" value="2"> {!$Label.Two} 
       <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" action="{!ctrl.submitSatisfactionComment}" rerender="myPanel"/>
    </input>
```

If you want to keep the action function, you are missing the `()` and can put the action functions in the form by themselves although it should work like you have it after you add the `()`

```
<apex:form>
       <apex:actionFunction name="satisfactionComment" action="{!ctrl.submitSatisfactionComment}" rerender="myPanel"/>

<input type="radio" onclick="satisfactionComment();"  name="satisfaction" value="1"> {!$Label.One}
    </input>
<input type="radio" onclick="satisfactionComment();"  name="satisfaction" value="2"> {!$Label.Two} 
    </input>
</apex:form>
```

Now, how you pass the value? You can use merge fields if applicable instead of 1 or 2 or you can pass to the action function using the param tag...

```
<apex:form>
       <apex:actionFunction name="satisfactionComment" action="{!ctrl.submitSatisfactionComment}" rerender="myPanel">
           <apex:param value="" name="myParam" assignto="{!MYVAR}"/>
       </apex:actionfunction>

<input type="radio" onclick="satisfactionComment(this.value);"  name="satisfaction" value="1"> {!$Label.One}
    </input>
<input type="radio" onclick="satisfactionComment(this.value);"  name="satisfaction" value="2"> {!$Label.Two} 
    </input>
</apex:form>
```

Also, if using  breaks 508 compliance you may want to open a case with SF support. Just a thought and not sure if applicable as I do not deal with 508 compliance so just throwing it out there.